How to align text to the left side of a page an equation to the middle, while both reside on the same line?
In case the title isn't clear: I need a bit of text and an equation (for other cases, in the provided picture I had other text) to reside on the same exact line, while having the text be aligned to the left side of the page and the equation be aligned to the center.
The best solutions I could come up with are the following, but they don't lead to the desired result (pictures below):
Desired Result:

Solution 1:
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \textit{Behauptung.}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{1.5\textwidth}
    $f$ ist irreduzibel über $K$.
\end{minipage}

Result 1:

Solution 2:
\begin{center}
    \begin{raggedright}
    \textit{Behauptung.}
        \begin{equation}
            f \text{ ist irreduzibel über } K. \nonumber
        \end{equation}
    \end{raggedright}
\end{center}

Result 2:

Huge thanks to anybody helping out in advance :O)!

What behavior do you expect if there is more text and/or a longer equation? You could also try using some form of tables.

Its literally one word + not even a full sentence, fitting this into a single line shouldn't be a problem because of the amount of space..

I don't want to be held responsible for unwanted results (e.g. text overlap), but here is one way of doing it:
\textit{Behauptung.}\\[-2\baselineskip] $$f \text{ ist irreduzibel über } K.$$


This is not ideal formatting though, and you can also have a look at the discussion here, particularly suggesting to use \shortintertext in a gather environment instead: Equation with numbering on the right and text on the left
